# Can a Camel route SEND data to a TCP client?

Tags: tcp, apache-camel, netty

A TCP client will be connecting to our server to receive data, it will not be sending data. I would like to set up a Camel route to transmit data to the client, is this possible?

Comment: Check out netty tcp component. It should be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with netty.

I hope this link helps you:

http://camel.apache.org/netty4.html